# Persistence of the 1:m relation which don't have individual entity but dependent on root aggregate/entity + DDD

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, entity, ddd-repositories, value-objects

Let's say we have a cafe enity/AR and it has regular opening hours and some explicit opening and closing hours as attriubutes (VO).

Each cafe can have multiple sets of opening and closing hours including regular hours.

```
let Cafe = {
   guid: "askdlaksldklaskl12l3k1l2klaskd",
   name: "My Cafe",
   location: "New York",
   coordinate: ['74.2344","77,12332"],
   star_rating: "4",
   images: [
      "someurl", "someother url"
   ],
   is247: false,
   opening_hours: {
      regular_hours: [
         {
            weekday: 1,
            start: "10: 00 am",
            closing: "6: 00 pm"
         },
         {
            weekday: 2,
            start: "10: 00 am",
            closing: "6: 00 pm"
         },
         {
            weekday: 3,
            start: "10: 00 am",
            closing: "6: 00 pm"
         }

      ],
      explicit_closing: [{
         start: "2022/07/12 3:00",
         end: "2022/07/15: 6:00"
      },
      {
         start: "2022/08/10 3:00",
         end: "2022/08/13: 6:00"
      }],
      explicit_opening: [{
         start: "2022/09/12 3:00",
         end: "2022/09/15: 6:00"
      }]
   }
}
```

Here cafe can have guid and is agregate root,and  opening/closing/regular hours don't need such guid it can have some db unique id though.

I have made opening_hours as value object in domain layer, if we are storing it to persistence.

The persistence storage logic depends upon what kind of database we are using,
If we were to use mongodb(nosql document db) we can directly map to the station entity and store as it is, for mysql do we need to create different tables for opening hours or other VO which has collection with 1:n mapping.

For mysql (RDBMS) do we need to normalise database and make different tables for relational VO or keep one table per entity. (As it makes more sense to keep normalised data in RDBMS else its use are same as nosql)

Let's say for querying we need to fetch all the cafe's which are open with radius 10km range based on coordinate value.

Though the decision of db selection and its logic should be independent of the domain layer in DDD, however I need some right direction to approach these decision making.

Answer (score 0):

Part of being a value object is that any copy of it can be substituted for any other.  So in that sense, it's OK to have an `opening_hours` table and have entities refer to that object via a foreign key.  If doing this, you'll need to make sure that you never do an `UPDATE` on the `opening_hours` table (just `INSERT`s and maybe `DELETE`s) and enforce a uniqueness constraint on `(start, closing)`.

The `UPDATE` prohibition arises because

- value objects are immutable
- updating a value object which is incorporated into multiple instances of an aggregate (which is implied by normalizing: there's no way to ensure that a given value object is in only one instance of an aggregate that doesn't imply at least one of breaking an aggregate boundary or denormalizing) implies breaking an aggregate boundary by updating another instance of an aggregate as part of updating another instance

For a similar reason, an `ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE` would also be frowned upon in DDD.

There's an uneasy relationship in practice between DDD and relational DB normalization: the various (even arguably 1NF) normal forms tend to entail breaking aggregate boundaries or encoding domain logic in the infrastructure layer (e.g. uniqueness constraints).  The latter doesn't necessarily cause a problem, but encoding that logic in the infrastructure means that you're either duplicating that logic in the domain layer/ring/whatever of your system (duplication of logic is at least questionable and opens the door for "[my domain logic's saying let's go, but my infrastructure's saying no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIDWgqDBNXA&t=38s)" situations) or your domain layer/ring/whatever not capturing some important part of the domain rules.  Accordingly, there's a tendency among at least some DDD practitioners to not go that high into the *NFs, even though one might point out that doing so might be paying the price of supporting higher NFs without getting the benefit (in which case those practitioners might be better off using NoSQL/key-value stores, perhaps ones with stronger consistency guarantees than the common ones, but still NoSQL).